How to convert <br/> tags to xml &#xa; line breaks with xslt?
[XSLT 1.0]
I have this in my xml input :
<p>line-break test<br clear="none"/>line-break test<br clear="none"/>line-break test</p>
I'd just need to replace each <br/> tag with a proper xml line break. How to do this with xsl ?

Create a template that matches the br element and emit &#xa; when it matches on that element.
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="br">
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

